# Cast or Forged Alloy Wheels: Is there any way to determine the difference when buying?

Tags: wheels

As I've looked at alloy wheels on several different websites (Amazon, America's Tire, Tire Rack, etc.) I haven't noticed in the description whether or not the wheel is cast or forged. Other than possibly price-point is there any way for the average person to know if a wheel is cast or forged? If it's possible to tell from the price, what would be the cost difference between cast and forged wheels? The wheels that came with my '14 Honda Accord are 1,600 USD each, so I'm guessing that there is probably a huge cost difference between cast and forged wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a huge cost difference between cast (cheaper) and forged (2x-4x pricier) wheels, but only a small increase in wheel strength (forged wheel are ~20% stronger). However, the finishing process makes both wheels looks pretty much the same.

You have 2 options to tell them apart:

- usually, there will be "CAST" or "FORGED" stamped into the wheel, usually on the back side
- look up the specific wheel model on the manufacturer's website